# Wordpress category/taxonomy query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I need to get all my posts in wordpress only from my category 6 and only this one, I dont want to query posts with 2 categorys like posts "X" has categories 6 and 9.
I'm stuck on this part of my query, and wanto to know if I should use NOT IN, and if that will make my query to much slower ?

```
 SELECT p.*, t.term_id
        FROM wp_posts p
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
        WHERE t.term_id = 6
        ORDER BY p.post_date DESC Limit 10;
```

Comment: You wan to display your posts in front end ? No need to make an SQL query. You can use some native WordPress method i think.

Comment: No, I'm just want the data to make a mobile front with only a specific category, will not use wordpress in this app

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get all the terms and remove all terms ids that not equal to terms_id that you wanted.

check this. I added some comments to explain the process

```
function get_posts_from_single_cat($cat_id) {
    // Get all the categories
    $cats = get_terms(array('taxonomy'=>'category'));
    $cats_ids = array();
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        // Check if the category is NOT equal to the category that we want
        // Then we add it into array
        if($cat->term_id !== $cat_id) {
            $cats_ids[] = $cat->term_id;
        }
    }

    // then we create WP_Query with the category that we want and checking that its not in the other categories
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => array( $cat_id )
            ),
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $cats_ids,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // then do something with the posts...
}
```